# Jquery: one element click and one element change in single function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two elements. I have to do same code logic for one element's click and another element's change. How can I combine these 
two to avoid code duplication. I am looking for a solution other than calling a same function from both the events.

```
$( "element1" ).change(function(){
    //some stuff here
});

$( "element2" ).click(function(){
    //same above stuff here
});
```

Comment: Why not calling the same function? You could have `$("element1").change(sharedFunction)` and `$("element2").click(sharedFunction)`

Comment: Hey... I just noticed that: *«I am looking for a solution other than calling a same function from both the events.»*... What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Put your "stuff" in an outer function...
Then call this function in your event handlers.

```
function myStuff(){
  //some stuff here
}


$( "element1" ).change(myStuff);

$( "element2" ).click(myStuff);
```

Comment: @quirimmo: Thank for the edit... I approved it. ;) *(I doesn't change anything... But it's more concise)*

Comment: thanks :) yeah I just like to avoid inner functions when we can omit them :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, but you could use the same callback function for each event.

```
var callback = function(e) {
  //shared functionality
}

$( "element1" ).change(callback);

$( "element2" ).click(callback);
```